# Regression with random input variables

Tags: regression, sampling, random-variable

Take a black-box model which is expensive to evaluate. Say you have $N$ observations of this black-box model denoted $\{Y_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ at the points $\{X_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$. We take an input of dimension one to simplify the problem. You know that the input $X$ follows Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. From these $N$ observations, you want to build a predictor in order to obtain a prediction at an unobserved point $x^{\star}$ through Gaussian Process Regression, for instance.

Now my question. You have the choice to pick where the points $\{X_i\}_{i=1,\ldots, N}$ are. Assume that you choose an LHS experiment design. I know that the basic LHS experiment design gives you points that follow a uniform distribution. Should you use the basic LHS experiment design or change it so that they follow a Normal distribution?

Comment: It just depends on what you are trying to optimize.

Comment: Do you recommend any book exploring this aspect?

Comment: General math stat knowledge - nothing in particular.  Wherever you saw LHS (whatever that is) must have some references though.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by it depends on what you are trying to optimize?

Comment: Which predictions do you wish to be most accurate? The answer to that question should lead to a loss function, probably involving variance. Then you can choose the x points to minimize it.